# OneSignal and userNotificationCenter(didReceive)

Tags: swift, onesignal

I need to get integer delivered by API request when the app gets push notification using One signal to update the badge icon's number. My AppDelegate is like this.
I want to send API request every time the app gets push notifications, but is it possible?

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    OneSignal.setAppId(Constants.OneSignalAppId)
    OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
    })
    return true
  }

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let request = APIRequest()
    Session.send(request) { result in
      switch result {
      case .success(let data):
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = data.totalUnreadMessageDetailCount
        }
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
      }
    }
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let request = APIRequest()
    Session.send(request) { result in
      switch result {
      case .success(let data):
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = data.totalUnreadMessageDetailCount
        }
        completionHandler(.badge)
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Do your delegate methods get called?

Comment: @burnsi There are no errors, and delegate methods don't get called. I put some breakpoints inside the userNotificationCenter methods but they don't stop the program..